# How do you get a Facebook photo's source URL using the facebook graph api?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Could you tell me how to use graph api to get the source url for a photo? Because I have the photo id and it seems like I should be able to make a call to get the source url.

As an example of what I'm trying to do, the following code works:

```
-(IBAction)showPicture:(UIButton *)sender;
{
    //code to retrieve picture

    id path = @"http://photos-e.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc1/v5041/89/51/40796308305/a40796308305_1960517_6704612.jpg";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData  *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    [self.label setText: (NSString *)path];
    imageView.image = img;
    [img release];

}
```

However that works when I have the source url. Is there a way to use graph api so that I can substitute `id path = @"http://..."` for something like `id path = [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"98423808305/source" andDelegate:self];` ???

---

Updated to include request didLoad method

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {


    if ([request.params objectForKey:@"picture"]) {
        // Get photo ID from result
        NSString *photoId = (NSString *)[result objectForKey:@"id"];
        shitStorm = photoId;
    }


  if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
  }
  if ([result objectForKey:@"owner"]) {
    [self.label setText:@"Photo upload Success"];
  } else {
    [self.label setText:[result objectForKey:@"name"]];
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"YOUR_PHOTO_ID" andDelegate:self];
```

then in the request response you'll get every information about the picture. See an example here:
https://graph.facebook.com/98423808305
Grab your required info, might against the key "source", and use it as you want. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ this is a very good place to learn while developing with FB.

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result {  
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
    NSArray *keys=[result allKeys];
    NSLog(@"%@",keys);
    NSString *imageURL=[result objectForKey:@"source"];
    //here you can use this imageURL to get image-data and display it in imageView  
}
```

Might this will give you idea how to sort different requests.

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result{
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
    NSString *requestType =[request.url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/" withString:@""];
    if ([requestType isEqualToString:@"me"]) {
        //Request to get User's Profile info
    }
    else if ([requestType isEqualToString:@"me/picture"]) {
        //this is the request to get User's Profile Picture
    }   
}
```

Similarly you can sort different requests and hence perform different request specific tasks.

Comment: Hi Admed, thanks for your reply - we both used the same FB example :-) But I understand what the request response looks like. I don't understand how to grab the required info. So using your example, would I do something like `id path = [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"YOUR_PHOTO_ID" andDelegate:self"]; followed by NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[(NSString *)[path objectForKey:@"source"]]];` ... Is that what you're telling me to do?

Comment: no NateHill you need to implement the fbRequestDelegateProtocol.. in it's requestdidload method, I reckon, you'll get the required data. The response is likely to be in dictionary format. You should NSLOG all the response you received to get a better understanding. Tell me if that helps or I would try to put some example code too.

Comment: It kind of helps. Could you please put some example code? I included my request didLoad method so if you could use that for your example that would be great. I guess I'm confused as to where the "code" should go. In my showPicture method I just call  `[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"YOUR_PHOTO_ID" andDelegate:self"]` and then in my request didLoad method I put the actual code to load the UIImage view? If so, how does that method know when to do what?

Comment: NateHill check out the edits and code snippet. Hope that'll help

Comment: Brilliant! Worked perfectly :-) Thanks again @Ahmed. One last question. Since there are a lot of requests going to request didLoad, how should I organize that area? Because I feel like each request will go through this display image block of code too - and I don't want that.

Comment: NateHill..I've added bit modified requestDidLoad method, have a look, might it'll help. Let me know if it does:)

Comment: Hi @Ahmed, once again thank you very much. That is very helpful. What should I do when my requestWithGraph path is something like `graphUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/comments", photoID];` ... Would I sort requests like this? `if ([requestType isEqualToString:@"%@/comments"])` ... or would I need to alter the isEqualToString? Thanks again. This seems much better than using booleans to decide what should be done and what shouldn't :-)