# Facebook sdk How can I get url from photo id

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I use FBRequestConnection to get photo's id and post id

But I want to know the photo's URL

How can I do ?

I did use [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:id] , but no URL return

Thanks for help

Comment: Have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613342/how-do-you-get-a-facebook-photos-source-url-using-the-facebook-graph-api

Answer (score 1):

Usually url's of image posts returned with every graph object but if you want to get profile image

"http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture"

Where id can be profile id or user name .e.g.

http://graph.facebook.com/jansharkhan/picture